# GWT Maven plugin replace web.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I have the following maven configuration
my goal is to replace web-xml for development mode from usual web.xml to web-dev.xml
gwt-maven-plugin seems to have configuration wor it (webXml) but it's not working not as eclipse plugin (run as web application), not when mvn gwt:run.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                <style>PRETTY</style>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-dev.xml</webXml>
                <inplace>true</inplace>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what [the doc says](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html), the `webXml` configuration parameter is actually only used for the [`mergewebxml`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/mergewebxml-mojo.html) goal (almost useless nowadays).

Try doing things the other way around: `web.xml` for dev, and a `web-prod.xml` for prod that you configure in the `maven-war-plugin`, as `gwt:run` will copy your `src/main/webapp` as-is, bypassing any configuration you could have made for the `maven-war-plugin`.